# WSL configuration on an external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL with Ubuntu distro installed on my external hard drive on Windows 11 Home. It takes only half of my system's RAM, and I want to increase the limit. I tried setting the configurations on the `.wslconfig` file and `wsl.conf` file, but the changes does not take effect. How do I do it?

Comment: Hi! this is really about the windows side of the WSL2 virtual machine, which we have very little experience with here; we care about what is inside, not outside WSL2 :-) I'd recommend asking on superuser.com, there's more Windows-experienced folks there!

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the guidance

Comment: As above. Also, in ANY case, be it any WSL solution or more traditional virtualization, you should never assign more than 50% of the resources (CPUs/RAM) of the host system. So, now, you don't need to ask.